# Помогите со скачивающим и распаковывающим скриптом

Tags: файлы, curl, php

Помогите со скачивающим и распаковывающим скриптом, после выполнения выдает ошибку: PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : Missing archive file '/domains/adminooo.lermnet.ru/PCMS.zip'

Код в студию:

---

```
<?php
include "config.php";
 // Получаем данные из формы
 $us= $_POST['us'];
 $snm= $_POST['surname'];
 $nm= $_POST['name'];
 $up= $_POST['us_pass'];
 $ph= $_POST['phone'];
 $org= $_POST['org'];
 $em= $_POST['e-mail'];

 //Склеиваем адрес
 $dr='/domains/'.$us.'.';
 $dir =$dr.$dm;
 $site= $us.'.'.$dm;

//Склеиваем название 
 $s_title='Профсоюзная организация ';
 $s_name= $s_title.$org;

// Переменные для качалки
$origFileName = $dir.'/'; //Путь до себя
$sourceFileName = '/domains/lermnet.ru/ftp/PCMS.zip'; //Скачиваемый файл

// Качаем двигло
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceFileName);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$st = curl_exec($ch);
$fd = @fopen($origFileName, «w»);
fwrite($fd, $st);
@fclose($fd);

curl_close($ch);

//Распаковываем архив с двиглом
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
$archive = new PclZip($origFileName.'PCMS.zip');
if ($archive->extract() == 0) die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
else echo('Ok!');
?>
```

Comment: Код нормально оформи, потом может быть получишь ответ

Comment: У вас архив лежит в папке ftp? Скрипт пытается открыть его в корне

Comment: да в ftp лежит
А какой именно скрипт? Скачка или распаковка

Comment: При распаковке

Comment: спасибо Zamony